# Unable to create a wireless hotspot menu not showing

Tags: wireless, connection

So i'm trying to to create a wireless hotspot on my Linux but it's not working, whenever i press turn on wireless hotspot nothing happens.

Anyone knows whats the problem and how can it be fixed, following tutorials shows theres another menu that should appear but nothing happens.

[image: when i press this button nothing happens]

[image: After clicking turn on]

Comment: Do you have a wired connection?

Comment: @Arronical yes i do, the problem is no window shows after i press turn on or nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

From what is see from your screen-shots, you have your wireless connection off, you have to turn it on before making it a Hotspot.

Creating a Wi-Fi Hotspot from setting only worked in Ubuntu gnome for me. but there is another way to do it.

1. Go to a terminal by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and copy past this into it:

   sudo apt-get install kde-nm-connection-editor
2. after install open the KDE connection editor from the dash, or by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> and run `kde-nm-connection-editor` to launch it.
3. Click the <kbd>Add</kbd> button and choose `Wireless (shared)` from the list.
4. Type in a name, ssid, and select `Access Point mode` and set up a password under the Wireless Security tab and click <kbd>OK</kbd>.
5. click Network Manager applet on Unity panel and then choose `Connect to Hidden Wi-Fi network`, choose the connection you created in the previous step and click the <kbd>Connect</kbd> button.

Now go to your phone and most see your hotspot ssid there!

### Enjoy!  :-)

NOTE: you mad need to press <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> to run the command, depending in your BIOS setting.

Comment: i encountered a problem, E: Unable to locate package kde-nm-connection-editor, also i this was an illustration still happens the same with wireless activateed

Comment: try installing it from Ubuntu software center.

Comment: sorry for the late reply.. but it's already installed and there is no (wireless shared), only Wi-Fi and it on uses adhoc and infrastructure modes ?